# How to hide woocommerce custom tab when the content is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I just add 4 custom tabs in woocommerce single product page. Now I want to hide these tabs if there is no content. Here is my custom tabs code. How can I do that?  Automatically description tab is not showing if there is no content. Another question is for the review tab. Can I hide it also if there is no review or comments? 
Thanks in advance.

```
// Add a custom metabox

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'additional_product_tabs_metabox' );
function additional_product_tabs_metabox()
{
add_meta_box(
    'add_product_metabox_additional_tabs',
    __( 'Additional product Tabs', 'woocommerce' ),
    'additional_product_tabs_metabox_content',
    'product',
    'normal',
    'high'
);
}

//  Add custom metabox content
function additional_product_tabs_metabox_content( $post )
{
// Indicated For
echo '<h4>' . __( 'Indicated for', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_indicated_for', true );
wp_editor( $value, '_indicated_for', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );

// Caution
echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Caution', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_caution', true );
wp_editor( $value, '_caution', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );


// How To
echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'How To', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_how_to', true );
wp_editor( $value, '_how_to', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );

//Part of Cure Series

echo '<br><hr><h4>' . __( 'Part of Cure Series', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_part_of_cure_series', true );
wp_editor( $value, '_part_of_cure_series', array( 'editor_height' => 100 ) );

// Nonce field (for security)
echo '<input type="hidden" name="additional_product_tabs_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';
}


// Save product data
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'save_additional_product_tabs', 10, 1 );
function save_additional_product_tabs( $post_id ) {

// Security check
if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'additional_product_tabs_nonce' ] ) ) {
    return $post_id;
}

//Verify that the nonce is valid.
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'additional_product_tabs_nonce' ] ) ) {
    return $post_id;
}

// If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return $post_id;
}

if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) ) {
    return $post_id;
}

// Sanitize user input and save the post meta fields values.

if( isset($_POST[ '_indicated_for' ]) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_indicated_for', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_indicated_for' ]) );

if( isset($_POST[ '_caution' ]) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_caution', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_caution' ]) );

if( isset($_POST[ '_how_to' ]) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_how_to', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_how_to' ]) );

if( isset($_POST[ '_part_of_cure_series' ]) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_part_of_cure_series', wp_kses_post($_POST[ '_part_of_cure_series' ]) );

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

// 1) Removing tabs

//unset( $tabs['description'] );              // Remove the description tab
//unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab



//Attribute Indicated for
$tabs['intend_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Intend For', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_indicated_for_tab_content'
);

// Adds the Caution tab
$tabs['caution_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Caution', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 60,
    'callback'  => 'woo_caution_tab_content'
);

// Adds the how to tab
$tabs['how_to'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'How To', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 70,
    'callback'  => 'woo_how_to_content'
);

 // Adds the _part_of_cure_series

$tabs['part_of_cure_series'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Part of Cure Series', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 80,
    'callback'  => 'woo_part_of_cure_series'
);



$tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 90;

return $tabs;
}


function woo_indicated_for_tab_content()  {
global $product;


echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_indicated_for' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_caution_tab_content()  {
global $product;

echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_caution' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_how_to_content()  {
global $product;

echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_how_to' ) . '</p></div>';
}

function woo_part_of_cure_series()  {
global $product;

echo'<div><p>'. $product->get_meta( '_part_of_cure_series' ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late answering but this is generic and can be useful for someone

```
    /**
     * Remove product data tabs when the content is empty
     */
    function demo_remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
        foreach ( $tabs as $key=>$product_tab) {
            if ( isset( $product_tab['callback'] ) ) {
                ob_start();
                call_user_func( $product_tab['callback'], $key, $product_tab );
                $tab_content = ob_get_clean();
                if (empty($tab_content)){
                    unset($tabs[$key]); 
                }
            }
        }
        return $tabs;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'demo_remove_product_tabs', 98 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows code snippets in your active theme's functions.php to achieve the above -

```
function modify_woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    global $product;
    // Remove tabs if contents data are empty
    if( isset($tabs['intend_tab'] ) && !$product->get_meta( '_indicated_for' ) ) {
        unset( $tabs['intend_tab'] ); 
    }
    if( isset($tabs['caution_tab'] ) && !$product->get_meta( '_caution' ) ) {
        unset( $tabs['caution_tab'] ); 
    }
    if( isset($tabs['how_to'] ) && !$product->get_meta( '_how_to' ) ) {
        unset( $tabs['how_to'] ); 
    }
    if( isset($tabs['part_of_cure_series'] ) && !$product->get_meta( '_part_of_cure_series' ) ) {
        unset( $tabs['part_of_cure_series'] ); 
    }
    if( isset($tabs['reviews'] ) && $product->get_review_count() ) {
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] ); // unset reviews
    }
    return $tabs;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'modify_woo_custom_product_tabs', 999 );
```